# sending mesage via net send to another pc

Tags: windows, batch, command-line

I am trying to send a message to another pc on my company network.

I do it like

```
net send pc14.name.com "my msg"
```

but i get

```
An error occurred while sending a message to PC14.NAME.COM.

The message alias could not be found on the network.
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

First step: make sure the messenger service is set to Automatic and is running (Started) on both PCs. It may only be needed on the recipient PC.

Second step: look for the PC's name in the output of the "net view" command and send your message to that name. Otherwise try sending the message to the user using their username.

Answer (score 0):

`net send` uses netbios names to determine where to send messages, not domain names. If this is on a local network, then make sure the PC in question has `PC14.NAME.COM` in the list displayed by `net name`. If you want to send messages across the internet, you'll need to implement the messaging layer yourself.

Comment: i am trying to send on the local netrwork.
and the pc14.name.com  is the pc name .  
but still it not working

Comment: Just being the PC's name doesn't mean it is necessarily in `net name`. It needs to be listed in `net name` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try a computer name or netbios name instead of an URL.

Comment: I am sending via the pc name , and get that error .
How i get that netbios name ?

Comment: You can get a list of netbios names associated with a PC by running `net name`

Comment: i get following error
The Messenger service is not started.

Is it OK to start it? (Y/N) [Y]: y
System error 1058 has occurred.

The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has n
o enabled devices associated with it.

Comment: Then there's your first problem. In recent iterations of Windows the Messenger service is disabled (not just off, but disabled) by default. It needs to be running to recieve (and send for that matter, I believe) messages. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984431%28VS.71%29.aspx You want the one about the Service Control Manager